# Facebook invite people for my app from user friend list

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios7

I was using ios friend request dialog from facebook to send invitation to user for my app. After facebook announced closing of their API it stopped working, Does anyone have an idea how to invite people for application for ios.

Comment: Facebook listed it in their FAQ: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Comment: @WizKid so I have to use message dialog to send invitation..m i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has announced that this will work only for Games application, though one can do this. Just set canvas url for app on Facebook app and use faecbook request dialog. This is very usefull feature for any app.Facebook is working on this feature to make available easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
- (void)inviteFriendsOfFacebook
{
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[mArrTempSelected componentsJoinedByString:@","], @"suggestions", nil];

    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                                  message:textView.text
                                                    title:nil
                                               parameters:params
                                                  handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                                      if (error) {
                                                          // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                                                          NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
                                                      } else {
                                                          if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                              // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                                                              NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                                                          }
                                                          else
                                                          {
                                                              [Helper showAlertForMessage:@"Invitation Sent Successfully." title:nil cancelButton:@"Ok" otherButton:nil andDelegate:nil withTag:0];

                                                          }

                                                      }}];

}
```

Comment: I have used same...but now onwards it will not send request to user.Please check and confirm with your code...and also check whethre that person got request or not.

Comment: Yes, I have tested it with same code and invitation sent successfully. But it is not showing on web, it is showing only on iOS device after some time.